# Understanding `extends (...args: unknown[]) => unknown`

Tags: typescript

Why does `Bar` below return `false` and how could one make it so that it behaves similarly to `Foo` - which basically returns true if the type is a function?

```js
// type Foo operates as I expected
type Foo = ((str: string) => void) extends (...args: any[]) => any ? true : false         // true

// why does this function not extend (...args: unknown[]) => unknown?
type Bar = ((str: string) => void) extends (...args: unknown[]) => unknown ? true : false // false?
```

A hacky solution would be to simply use `Foo` instead of `Bar` are there any better options that don't use `any` which is discouraged?

`unknown` is the top type and so `T extends unknown ? true : false` always returns `true`, except for `never`.  `any` behaves similarly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments of the function behave differently from its return value in terms of subtyping.

Let's see it at more simple example:

```
type UniversalHandler = (arg: number | string) => number;
type NumberHandler = (arg: number) => number;
```

Here, `number | string` is a kind of "top type" for the part of the TypeScript type system, so we can treat it (for the sake of specific example) the same as `unknown`. Now, here're the functions of these two types:

```
const uni: UniversalHandler = (arg) => typeof arg === 'number' ? arg : arg.length;
const num: NumberHandler = (arg) => arg;
```

Now it should be obvious that `uni` is also a `NumberHandler` (it will just always take the "is number" path), but `num` is *not* a `UniversalHandler` - given a string, it will return a string, not a number. That is, the function which accepts the "top type" is assignable to the function which accepts its subtype - not the other way around.
This is called [contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types), and that's how the "subtyping by function argument" usually works.

Now, back to the example. You now see that the "top type among functions" must not accept the top type as an argument, since other functions will not be assignable to it. Instead, it must be the most restrictive in its arguments - it must accept the *bottom* type, that is, `never`:

```
type Baz = ((str: string) => void) extends (...args: never[]) => unknown ? true : false // true
```

---

As for why it works with `any` - the reason is that `any` is not a "true" top type, it's a kind of hybrid. Everything is assignable to `any`, which makes it similar to a top type, - but `any` is assignable to anything, too, which makes it work wherever the bottom type is expected.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  Why [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKAKAUFKBLAdmAV2AC4pcIA3CAJwBpMpqIBnAgG2AGEAjU1AOkEBDagHNmpArgDWuOAHdcAbQC6ASmQA+MpRq0oAegNQAZnGpQAxnFzNszYBFyWQUeQAtXAEzgsdValUyOGA3c2kodxoIAH50DSRtcgD0dFBIKAAhEWQ0DCw8QhIoJQohNgIIUlwCAFtuGhV6LCZWDh4+AA8JMjqG6gTtB2o8UXpB-xoNCE7HXC9mWAQoGKhgakqoUhNy5gh0IA) is unkown[] required and not never[]?

Comment: You want to use the "bottom function type" as argument to `Foo`, so that `Foo` is the kinda "top function type" itself. And the "bottom function type" is the one which is most liberal in what it accepts, i.e. which accepts `unknown`. The same logic, just used twice in a row.