# What does a spread operator in typescript mean?

Tags: typescript

I found the following generic type definition. It expects a function with arguments. But what does the spread mean and the array of any?

```
type ReturnOf<F> = F extends {(...arg: any[]) : infer R} ? R : never
```

Comment: I don't think its right syntax, its showing errors in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play).

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72960424/understanding-extends-args-unknown-unknown

Comment: @bogdanoff I edited the question, you were right

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#rest-parameters-and-arguments

Comment: its a function signature, since a `function` is also form of `Object`.  So Its same as ```type ReturnOf<F> = F extends (...arg: any[]) => infer R ? R : never```